# Sending emails from Bluemix failing

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, sendgrid

We've developed several applications hosted in Bluemix that use SendGrid to send emails. Since last week, everyone of these applications started failing after no changes whatsoever in none of them.

It turns out that Bluemix started timing out the requests to SendGrid. We thought it was SendGrid's problem, so we replaced the service with Amazon SES, and to our dismay, we started getting exactly the same error.

Here is what the logs look like:

[image]

We put together this simple NodeJS application that gives us the error to see if someone sees what's wrong, or tries it out and lets us know whether this is actually failing on a different Bluemix account:

## app.js

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8080;
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", function (request, response) {
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
        host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
        port: 25,
        auth: {
            user: "user",
            pass: "password"
        }
    });

    var mail = {
        from: "noreply@ibm.com",
        to: "user@companyXYZ.com",
        subject: "Send Email Using Node.js",
        text: "Node.js send email test",
        html: "<b>Node.js send email test</b>"
    };

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, resp){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            response.write(error);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + resp.message);
            response.write("Message sent: " + resp.message);
        }

        smtpTransport.close();

        response.end();
    });

});

app.listen(port);
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "ibm-email-nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "ibm email nodejs",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.x",
    "commander": "^2.6.0",
    "http-post": "^0.1.1",
    "http-proxy": "^1.8.1",
    "nodemailer": "0.7.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.9.1",
    "npm": "3.7.3"
  }
}
```

## manifest.yml

```
applications:
- path: .
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  domain: mybluemix.net
  name: ibm-email-nodejs
  host: ibm-email-nodejs
  disk_quota: 1024M
  command: node app.js
```

Comment: You published your user and pass. Please remove them.

Comment: From the docs : `Many hosting providers and ISPs block port 25 as a default practice. When trying to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net remember that ports 25, 2525, 587, and 465 are all available for use. You can connect via unencrypted or TLS on ports 25, 2525, and 587. You can also connect via SSL on port 465. Keep in mind that many hosting providers and ISPs block port 25 as a default practice. If this is the case, contact your host/ISP to find out which ports are open for outgoing smtp relay.` https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/smtp_ports.html

Comment: @svpino I removed the credentials.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, but I don't think that's the problem. As I mentioned on the question, we used Amazon SES as well (port 465) and it also failed.

Comment: You might consider contacting SendGrid Support (https://support.sendgrid.com) as they are a third-party service on Bluemix.

Comment: Thanks @BillWentworth, but the problem is not with SendGrid. It's trying to use any SMTP server, including Amazon SES.

Comment: Bluemix doesn't allow you to use port 25 (see also http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/outbound-email-port-25).

Answer (score 1):

The port 587 should work. Reference : http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/

Did you try that? Please check out the code at 
https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-nodejs/blob/master/examples/example.js

```
// Use nodemailer to send the email
var settings = {
    host: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: parseInt(587, 10),
    requiresAuth: true,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD
       }
    };
```